# How to Build WP Site with Hierarchical Content and Using Custom Design?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A client asked me to redesign her web site, built several years ago in WP by another developer.  Although I've never worked with WP before, I'm pretty comfortable with html, css, and php, and I more or less understand how WP stores content and dynamically builds pages.  But I'm wondering how to approach these challenges:

My client's site has about 75 pages.  There are about 25 that are static (i.e. the content changes infrequently if at all; things like "about us" and "faqs") and there are about 50 pages that are more "blog-like", except that instead of posts, the content contains directory-type info (e.g. 12 DJs in the area) or event-related info (e.g. upcoming shows at local theaters).  Both of these categories contain many sub (and sometimes sub-sub) categories (e.g. medical services > pediatric > kid allergy specialists) and the content updates fairly frequently.

I understand the difference in WP between "pages" and "posts".  But I need to find out the best way to structure the static content.  Should I just set up a parent/child hierarchy of pages, changing the permalinks to something that makes sense?  Or is it better / easier to just build the static pages *outside* WP and somehow link to them from the common navigation?

As a web designer, I want to "wow" my client with a great design.  While there are loads of wonderful WP themes available, I really need to create something unique.  But I'm wary of breaking something, so what's the best way to take an existing theme and just tweak it enough to make it look a little different?

Finally, other than mounting a massive "copy and paste" effort when the new site is built, is there a way to transfer content from the original site to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

By reading your question, it seems to me that choosing WP for this kind of website was a bad choice.

Redesigning it, though, won't be that hard if it's using page templates for pages.

And yes, there's a import/export tool in WP to tranfer content. (see administration panel)

I, really, advise you to read this [great tutorial](http://www.wpdesigner.com/2007/02/19/so-you-want-to-create-wordpress-themes-huh/) about creating WP themes.

Comment: Well, choosing WP wasn't really a choice - the client insisted on it.  Thanks for the link to the tutorial; I'll check it out shortly...

Answer (score 0):

I've a blog-like WP site myself (contains RPG development articles). Here's what I did. Nested static pages simply have parent-child hierarchy: /about/mingos - that's easy to understand and i value this kind of content organisation (personal opinion).

As for themes, there's a no-brainer tool that, while not exactly apt for real business, has the capability of letting you see how stuff will look in seconds, and can sometimes give you great ideas. It's called Artisteer and there's a demo on [its site](http://www.artisteer.com/) that you can have a look at. Try your design ideas with it, see how stuff will look like. I'm sure you can come up with some great ideas for a "wow" design :).

Exporting content, as Soufiane Hassou remarked, is possible from within the admin panel.

Comment: Thanks - the nested static pages in a parent-child hierarchy seems to make sense.  And I'm glad you mentioned Artisteer.  I heard about it recently, and it looked great, but I wasn't sure if it was all just eye candy or a legitimate tool.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rule out using categories to create your hierarchy. That way you'd get the benefit of cross categorization of DJs and venues by location to create a robust cross reference system. Pages don't get this benefit without extra work.

To make this in to a directory, though, is gonna either be heavy work on managing the pages or heavy work on creating a solution that will cross reference everything and bring the content together in a usable way on the front end.